# grep or sort according to a string

Tags: bash, search, compare

I'm trying to find a fast and easy method for searching a line in a file with another string.

Say I have this file:

```
line nr 1
another line over here
here's another line
something else
and more
```

Now I want to get the line that compares best to, for example, `a line here`. Which in this case would be `another line over here`. Note that `here's another line` is less alike and I don't need this.

Is there a way to sort the file or grep the line with the most matching words or best matching pattern? *edit: basically like what a search engine would do.

Something like: `$ cat file | sort --compare 'string'`

Comment: Is it like you want to pass a string or value and search that in the whole file? Kindly confirm once?

Comment: yes, basically like what a search engine would do. It lists the most matching results.